# POST not accepting int parameter

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, api, post

I have a problem with ASP.NET MVC3.

I'm trying to post some parameters to a JSONResult action. It works great when i use GET, but when i use POST, i get an error, because apparently when using POST, it won't accept my integer parameters as such, and say that the parameters dictionary contains a null value for them.

Anyone run across this before? Thanks.

Edit: some code, as requested:

```
public JSONResult PostingHere(string username, int someotherparameter) {
    //Code   
}
```

Really, that's all that matters, because the exception is thrown then and there when POSTing because apparantly a null value gets passed to the `someotherparameter` parameter. When using GET, as said before, it works just dandy.

The intended use is to post with a NSURLRequest from an iPhone, but I've been debugging with a firefox extension called *Poster* and i get the same result. Full error:

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'someotherparameter' of non-nullable type 'System.Int16' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult PostingHere(System.String, Int16)'*

Edit 2: By request, I'll add an example of calling the action which results in the error:

```
<form action="http://fullurlhere.com/Controller/PostingHere" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="astring" />
<input type="hidden" name="someotherparameter" value="100" />
<input type="submit" value="Brace for impact" />
</form>
```

Edit 3: The post data; never mind the discrepancy in variable names, these are the actual names of them.

[image: Result of the Post]

Edit 4: Adding to the mystery, the problem disappears when testing against a local server on my own computer, with the very same MVC Project the server is running. So the problem is likely within a server-side setting.

Solved: Turns out when i evalutated the request, that the server was redirecting me to https:// from the http://, causing me to lose my POSTed data. Thanks to everyone for being such good sports.

Comment: Non-answerable question without code. And when showing your code here are the relevant things: model, controller action, javascript, view.

Comment: Now that you have shown your controller action, please show how this action is invoked. If you are using AJAX, show your javascript code and if it is a simple `<form>` in the view show this as well.

Comment: someotherparamter can never receive a null value. int is a value type

Comment: @Rickard, correct, that's why the exception is thrown. To understand why this happens we must see how this action is called.

Comment: can you show the client code that is making the POST

Comment: @3nigma, exactly, that's where the problem lies.

Comment: what's with this someotherparameter vs companynumber? sure this is not misspelling?

Comment: The initial name of `someotherparameter` was just an example. I assure you the parameter names are in order.

Comment: try `<form action="http://www.fullurlhere.com/Controller/PostingHere" method="POST">` or just the www like `<form action="www.fullurlhere.com/Controller/PostingHere" method="POST">`

Comment: The error message doesn't fit the provided method signature. So what does the method look like in the first place? (it says int16 not int32 aka int) and could you please show code that matches the actual input. Creating stuff you believe to be the same will only help in obfuscating the picture not in solving the issue for you

Comment: Allrighty then, here it is: `public JsonResult JsonGetAvailableDropdowns(string userid, short companynumber)` But as stated in my latest edit, it seems to be a problem with server settings, rather than the code itself, since it works on my local server, but not the live one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Turns out when i evalutated the request, that the server was redirecting me to https:// from the http://, causing me to lose my POSTed data. Thanks to everyone for being such good sports.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public JSONResult PostingHere(string username, int? someotherparameter) {
    //Code   
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but the actual problem is that the parameter apparantly is passed a null when it shouldn't be, as i'm absolutely positive it's passed along with the request every single time. Setting it as nullable would probably just cause an error down the line when a database query is missing a parameter.

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom: I've seen a number of people who are "absolutely positive" about things until it turns out they're wrong :) Please show the relevant bits of code/html/whatever which are posting to this. A copy of a request body captured in Wireshark would be useful too.

Comment: Well, you could take a gander at the example form i wrote. I'll go about whipping up a copy of the body.

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom, the form you have shown works perfectly fine. It correctly sends all parameters. The browser also correctly sets the `Content-Type` to `application/www-form-urlencoded` when this form is posted. This is something that **doesn't happen** with your actual client code. Download and install Fiddler, sniff the HTTP traffic and you will see that this iPhone doesn't send a correct HTTP Post request. And if you want to get help and understand why this doesn't happen you will have to show, I repeat, the client code.

Comment: The problem is that i have tried the form i wrote, and an array of other methods of posting the data, like the firefox extension Poster, as said in my original post - Still the problem persists, and every single method for POSTing that data to the server results in the same error, i'm beginning to think the client actually has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom, are there some custom routes involved? Maybe the server expects you to send this int parameter as part of the route and not as part of the query string. Also I noticed that in the exception you are using int16 and not int32. Any chance you are trying to send a larger number than what int16 could hold?

Comment: The only way I've been able to reproduce your exception is when someotherparameter is missing or miss spelled.

Comment: The number always has a length of 3 digits, so overflow shouldn't be a problem. There's no custom routing going on at all, and as said, just changing the method from POST to GET makes it work correctly. So really to phrase my problem as correctly as i can _POSTing instead of GETting results in Int16 parameters being nulled_. All other parameters, strings etc, still work just fine with POST.

Comment: Change the code to public JSONResult PostingHere(string username, int? someotherparameter, FormCollection formCollection), debug it and have a breakpoint at first line of the method. Check the formCollection.AllKeys.Count() and string.Join("|", formCollection.AllKeys). Do you see it as 2 and userid|companynumber? If not, what are the values?